# nav bar not staying in header on initial paint, but is fine on refresh?

Tags: html, css

Here is the site - 
greenvillejs.org

There should be a nav bar in the header; for some people there is, for some people there isn't. But if you refresh It's in there on my computer. I've cleared the cache on 3 browsers and I'm still not having the problem so I'm not even sure how to test at this point other than asking other people.

here is the code -

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <img src="images/logo_header.png" alt="GreenvilleJS" class="logo">
            <ul class="nav">
                <a href="#about"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="#topics"><li>Topics</li></a>
                <a href="#footer"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
                <a href="http://bit.ly/1d3MK07" target="_blank"><li>Sign Up</li></a>
          </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
   html {
    background: #33352D;
    font: 14px/21px "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #1E1E1A;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(22,22,22);
  position: relative;
}

header li:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #1E1E1A;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px rgb(12,12,12);
  border: 1px solid rgb(22,22,22);
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Currently, I have the .logo position: absolute and the nav bar float: right. I also tried having the .logo display: inline-block.

This is pretty basic stuff, but i'm pulling my hair out. 
Please help,

Thanks

Comment: Working fine for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, and this is probably causing it to fail. You currently have `a` children within `ul` elements, which have `li` children of their own. The only element that can be a child of the `ul` element is `li`.

Replace:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <a href="#about"><li>About</li></a>
    ...
</ul>
```

With:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I remember seeing that, and thinking it was weird. You're a life saver!!

Answer (score 0):

see this, js fiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/n3Fte/

do not use `"li"` in `"a"` tags!